# Reference for the exterior product of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I'm looking for a textbook on linear/multilinear algebra where I can find an overview (definition &  properties, preferably with proofs) of the exterior product of operators
$$K_1\wedge...\wedge K_n(v_1\wedge...\wedge v_n) = K_1v_1\wedge...\wedge K_nv_n$$

Could you recommend one please? Thanks!

Comment: What you wrote down doesn't make sense but see the "box product" in Greub's *Multilinear Algebra*, 2nd ed.